# Kotlin coroutines takes longer than threads

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin and coroutines and I'm trying to understand the coroutines API, so it's quite possible that I'm doing something wrong. So I'm having the list of some sort of objects and I'm trying to apply some long-running processing on each of these objects.

```
val listOfFoos = listOf(Foo(1), ..., Foo(n))
listOfFoos.forEach { longRunningJob(it) }

fun longRunningJob(foo: Foo) {
    runBlocking{
        delay(2000) //hardcoded delay for testing
    }
    //do something else
}
```

Of course this is the perfect candidate for running it concurrently, so here it is using good old threads:

```
listOfFoos.map { thread(start = true) { longRunningJob(it) } }.forEach { it.join() }
```

When I measure the execution time of it using `measureTimeMillis` it gives me about 2 seconds, which seems perfectly fine as each `longRunningJob` runs in parallel.
But the coroutines are much better as it does not have such an overhead as threads for the context switch. So here is my implementation using coroutines:

```
val deferredResults =
    listOfFoos.map { GlobalScope.async { longRunningJob(it) } }
runBlocking {
    deferredResults.awaitAll()
}
```

But this implementation finishes the execution in about 4 seconds, which is not what I was expecting at all and if I add more elements to the list, the execution time increases as well.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The needed time to execute this code depends on the number of threads that are used for the computation. Your threading example does not define a bound and spawns as many threads as you have jobs. The coroutine example, on the other hand, dispatches all tasks to `GlobalScope` which internally uses the [`Dispatchers.Default`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) thread pool. This pool is limited:

> The default CoroutineDispatcher that is used by all standard builders like launch, async, etc. if no dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor is specified in their context.
>
> It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the maximal number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number CPU cores, but is at least two.

Let's say you have 4 cores. Running the code with 4 jobs will result in ~2s runtime because everything runs in parallel (note concurrency <> parallelism). But as soon as you have more than 4 tasks, one will have to wait until one of the first tasks has finished sine only 4 tasks can run simultaneously at any point.

You can change the dispatcher pool to one with more threads:

```
GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Please note that `delay` is a bad example of a long-running task. It does not block the caller thread since it's a real suspending function that only pauses the coroutine. You can actually run your code on `main` entirely:

```
runBlocking {
    val deferredResults =
        (0..10).map { async(Dispatchers.IO) { longRunningJob() } }
    deferredResults.awaitAll()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. About `delay`, it is wrapped in the `runBlocking`, doesn't it make it blocking?

Comment: No this is no "active waiting", the coroutine is just being suspended for the given duration.

Comment: What is the best way to replace it? As I understand, `Thread.sleep` will block the entire thread and all the coroutines can be stuck, an I right?

Comment: What do you mean "replace"? With coroutines, you would not use `Thread.sleep` instead. But it would work for your example. It will block exactly one thread, the one you're using it from

Comment: I mean to replace so it will be a good example of long-running task. Will it block the thread thus all the coroutines that run on this thread, or it will block only one coroutine?

Comment: I have changed my hardcoded `delay` to `Thread.sleep` and that doesn't change the picture. Also with using `Dispatchers.IO ` the thread example is still faster that coroutines

Comment: "still faster" means like milliseconds? You should not see 4ms vs 2ms anymore at least

Comment: No, not millis the difference is huge. I'm generating array of 1000 Foo objects. And threads perform in about 2 seconds, but coroutines in about half a minute

Comment: well you're spawning 1000 threads for this. The Dispatchers.IO is still limited to 64 threads. Then you have to create a custom thread pool with 1k threads in it (which I don't recommend anyway)

Comment: If I will create the thread pool with 1k threads then there is no point in using coroutines as it will still use the same amout of threads and will have the same contex switch overhead. But I'm expecting to have a better perfomange with coroutines with the less amount of threads due to have less overhead. And that's not what I'm expecting :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191162/discussion-between-s1m0nw1-and-sergii-bishyr).

Comment: Calling `delay` in `runBlocking` (that `longRunningJob` does) is essentially the same as calling `Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

runBlocking is a coroutine function. What it does exactly is 'runs the code in the main thread/calling thread'. So It is not creating parallel threads to run things.

To run your code asynchronously you should use launch function instead of runBlocking. It runs on [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) shared pool of threads.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
   delay(2000);
}
```